# Pushing to remote master branch from local branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch, push, bitbucket

I am using Git as my VCS. I have checkout the master and created the local branch from the master to work for specific ticket(for eg. fileuploadbranch). Made code changes, added the files changed to index. Then commit the changes using

```
git commit -m "xxxx"
```

Now i tried to push to the remote master using

```
git push -u origin --all
```

So in my bitbucket hosting services, i can able to see two branches namely master and fileuploadbranch.

I realised it was due to giving the git push with "--all" option. This makes all the branches to be pushed to remote.

So now i tried with push with

```
git push -u origin master
```

I believe it will be moved only to remote master. But in the bitbucket commits view, it shows the local branch name(fileuploadbranch) on the right hand side and it indicated me that the push is from the local branch.

1. Whether this changes will be available in remote master even we pushed it from the local branch?
2. why it shows the local branch name(RHS) in commits view in bitbucket?

Any help will be appreciated!!!...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push your local branch which you've called `file_upload_branch` (I added underscores here for readability—note that this affects every occurrence below), but call it `master` on the remote:

```
git push origin file_upload_branch:master  # see below about -u
```

The last argument to `push` here is called a "refspec", and you spell it out with two parts: a local-side identifier (typically a branch name), and a remote-side identifier (another, possibly different, branch name).  The colon character `:` serves to separate the two.

If you use only one name, leaving out the colon, git assumes you want the same name on each side.  (Which you just said is not what you wanted.)

If you leave out the refspec entirely (and don't use options like `--all`), git chooses what to push based on various configuration variables.  If you have not set any of them, all current versions of git use the method called `matching`:<sup>1</sup> your git, doing the `push` operation, asks the other side's git "what branches do you have now", takes the resulting list and sees which local branches you have that match, and pushes those.

With `--all` as a (pseudo) refspec, your side just asks to push every branch name you have, to the same name on the remote (as you discovered).

(The syntax `:branchname`, given as a refspec, asks the remote to *delete* the named branch.  You will probably want to use this to delete `file_upload_branch` on the remote.)

If you set the configuration variable `push.default` to `upstream`,<sup>2</sup> this changes the default action for `push` with no refspec to use the "upstream" name of the current branch.  That is, if you're on `file_upload_branch` and its "upstream" name on the remote (`origin`) is `master`, a plain:

```
git push origin
```

will act as if you wrote:

```
git push origin file_upload_branch:master
```

This is where the `-u` argument comes in: after `file_upload_branch` is successfully pushed to `master` on remote `origin`, `git push` will *set* file_upload_branch's "upstream" to `origin/master`.  You only need to do this once per branch; having set the upstream, and set `push.default` to `upstream`, future pushes will automatically "do what you wanted".

---

<sup>1</sup>In git version 2.0, the default value for `remote.pushdefault` is going to change to `simple`.  If you set your `--global` `remote.pushdefault` to `simple` now, you will be prepared for (and thus unaffected by) this change.  Or, if you prefer `upstream` as a personal default, you can set that and it should still work in 2.0.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `remote.pushdefault` can be set in both your per-user (i.e., `--global`) git configuration and also in a per-repo configuration.  The per-repo configuration will override the global configuration whenever both are set.  You can also set a rather dizzying array of additional configurations, though I wouldn't do any of that just yet :-) : `remote.origin.push`, `branch.file_upload_branch.remote`, and `branch.file_upload_branch.pushremote` can all affect the behavior of `git push`.  See the [git config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for full details.